# Is it possible to query a file or process hash using wmi?

Tags: powershell, wmi

I searched for any way to query a process hash.
assuming I was able to retrive the ExecutablePath using Win32_Process,
I would like to query the file's hash.

I'm trying to avoid using powershell but to achieve the same functiallity of "Get-FileHash".

Thank You!

edit:
I have tried to use win32_filespecification that supplied md5checksum, the problem was i could not find the relevant files (such as notepad.exe).

Comment: You can extract Hashes files with `certutil` in command line with a batch file here an example to test if you like [Processes_Services_Tasks_Startup.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZvWS1XL6) or this one [ExtractCmdLine_Hashes.bat](https://pastebin.com/fv3DY9d2)

Comment: Please can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62510852/edit) and add what did you tried as code until now !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch file to test :

```
@echo off
Title Get Notepad Hash
Set "App_Path=%windir%\system32\notepad.exe"
echo "%App_Path%"
@for /f "tokens=2 skip=3 delims= " %%a in ('Powershell Get-FileHash "%App_Path%"') do echo SHA256=%%a
Pause & Exit
```

**EDIT :**
***Get Process File Hash using WMIC and Certutil in command line***

You can give a try for the second batch file :

```
@echo off
cls & color 9E & Mode 95,5
Title Get Process File Hash using WMIC and Certutil in command line 
Set "TmpFile=%~dpn0_Tmp.txt"
Set "LogPathExe=%~dpn0_PathExe.txt"
Set "Hashes=%~dpn0_Hashes.txt"

echo(
echo(                ===========================================================
echo(                    Please wait a while ... Working is in progress....
echo(                ===========================================================

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "!TmpFile!" (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic process get ExecutablePath /format:list') do (
        @For /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
            set "Exe=%%b"
                If not defined Exe Set !Exe! 
                    echo "!Exe!"
        )
    )
)

Call :RemoveDuplicateEntry "!TmpFile!" "!LogPathExe!"
Del "!TmpFile!" 

> "!Hashes!" (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "!LogPathExe!"') do (
        @for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%~a" SHA256 ^| findstr /i /v "CertUtil"') do set "H=%%H"
            echo %%a=!H: =!
        )
    )
)

If Exist "!Hashes!"  Start "" "!Hashes!"  & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------
:RemoveDuplicateEntry <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Powershell  ^
$Contents=Get-Content '%1';  ^
$LowerContents=$Contents.ToLower(^);  ^
$LowerContents ^| select -unique ^| Out-File '%2'
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------
```

***The third batch script to check hashes on virustotal :***

```
@echo off
cls & color 9E & Mode 95,5
Title Get Process File Hash using WMIC and Certutil in command line 
Set "TmpFile=%~dpn0_Tmp.txt"
Set "LogPathExe=%~dpn0_PathExe.txt"
Set "Hashes=%~dpn0_Hashes.txt"
Set "Hash2Check_VirusTotal=%~dpn0_Hash2Check_VirusTotal.txt"
If Exist "%Hash2Check_VirusTotal%" Del "%Hash2Check_VirusTotal%"

echo(
echo(                ===========================================================
echo(                    Please wait a while ... Working is in progress....
echo(                ===========================================================

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "!TmpFile!" (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic process get ExecutablePath /format:list') do (
        @For /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
            set "ExecutablePath=%%b"
                If not defined ExecutablePath Set !ExecutablePath! 
                    echo "!ExecutablePath!"
        )
    )
)

Call :RemoveDuplicateEntry "!TmpFile!" "!LogPathExe!"
Del "!TmpFile!" 

> "!Hashes!" (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "!LogPathExe!"') do (
        @for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%~a" SHA256 ^| findstr /i /v "CertUtil"') do set "H=%%H"
            echo %%a=!H: =!
            >> "!Hash2Check_VirusTotal!" echo https://www.virustotal.com/old-browsers/file/!H: =!
        )
    )
)

cls
Echo(
Echo( Did you want to check the executable on Virustotal ? Just Type "Y" Or any key to Quit !
Set /p "Check="
If /I [!check!] EQU [Y] (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "!Hash2Check_VirusTotal!"') do ( Start "Chek SHA256 on VIRUSTOTAL" %%a & Timeout /T 10 /nobreak>nul)
) else (
    If Exist "!Hashes!"  Start "" "!Hashes!"  & Exit
)
Exit
::----------------------------------------------------
:RemoveDuplicateEntry <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Powershell  ^
$Contents=Get-Content '%1';  ^
$LowerContents=$Contents.ToLower(^);  ^
$LowerContents ^| select -unique ^| Out-File '%2'
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
this is exactly what I was trying to avoid.

I'm trying to accomplish this with WMI only.

Comment: Ok in this case [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62510852/edit)  and post your old code !

Comment: I have not code yet...
The best i did was: "get-wmiobject -class Win32_FileSpecification -ComputerName "LocalHost" -Namespace "root\CIMV2""

notepad.exe was not found in the exportetd data

Comment: @YotamMazurik Check my last edit and my last batch script code !